# Code golf: "Color highlighting" of repeated text

Tags: string, language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

(Thanks to greg0ire below for helping with key concepts)

The challenge:
Build a program that finds all substrings and "tags" them with color attributes (effectively highlighting them in XML).

The rules:

1. This should only be done for substrings of length 2 or more.
2. Substrings are just strings of consecutive characters, which may include non-alphabetic characters. Note that spaces and other punctuation do not delimit substrings.
3. Character casing cannot be ignored.
4. The "highlight" should be done by tagging the substring in XML. Your tagging should be of the form `<TAG#>theSubstring</TAG#>` where `#` is a positive number unique to that substring and identical substrings.
5. The priority of the algorithm is to find the longest substring, not how many times it matches within the text.

Note: The order of the tagging shown in the example below is not important. Its just used by the OP for clarity.

---

An example input:

```
LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimenbook.
```

---

A partially correct output (OP may NOT have completely replaced perfectly in this example)

```
<TAG1>LoremIpsum</TAG1>issimply<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2>of<TAG5>the</TAG5><TAG3>print</TAG3>ingand<TAG4>type</TAG4>setting<TAG6>industry</TAG6>.<TAG1>LoremIpsum</TAG1>hasbeen<TAG5>the</TAG5><TAG6>industry</TAG6>'sstandard<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2>eversince<TAG5>the</TAG5>1500s,whenanunknown<TAG3>print</TAG3>ertookagalleyof<TAG4>type</TAG4>andscrambledittomakea<TAG4>type</TAG4>specimenbook.
```

---

Your code should be able to handle edge cases, such as the following:

Example Input 2:

```
hello!TAG!</hello.TAG.</
```

Example Output 2:

```
<TAG1>hello</TAG1>!<TAG2>TAG</TAG2>!<TAG3></</TAG3><TAG1>hello</TAG1>.<TAG2>TAG</TAG2>.<TAG3></</TAG3>
```

---

The winner:

- Most elegant solution wins (judged by
  others comments, upvotes)
- Bonus
  points/consideration for solutions
  utilizing shell scripting

---

Minor clarifications:

- Input can be hard coded or read from a file
- The criteria remains "elegance", which admittedly IS slightly vague, but it also encapsulates simple character/line counts as well. Comments by others and/or upvotes are also indicative of how the SO community views the challenge

Comment: +1 Very interesting question. Are you going to look for the largest repeated pieces of text, or for the most repeated pieces of text? How are you going to name a "piece of text" (to me, it is a group of consecutive words)? An "expression"?

Comment: Hi greg - thanks for askiing... i actually need it for ANY string of bytes actually and the "largest" such string... :)

Comment: Hi RubiCon10. If you accept answers in all languages you might want to add the tags language-agnostic and rosetta-stone. Also: most elegant solution is not really code-golfing in my definition ;-) –

Comment: Testing for eloquence is 1. *not* [code-golf] 2. highly subjective and 3. not covered by the [special remit that has been made for code-golf](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/so-weekly-code-golf). In general, and despite the exception for [code-golf], Stack Overflow is not a place for contests.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl <del>206</del>, <del>189</del>, <del>188</del>, <del>199</del>, 157 chars

excluding original string and last print.

```
 #New algorithm that produces correct ouputs for many cases



    push@z,q/LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimenbook/;

    push@z,q/oktooktobookokm/;
    push@z,q!dino1</dino2</!;
    push@z,q!dino1TAG2dino3TAG!;

    ## loop for tests doesn't count
    for $z(@z) {
    print "input : $z\n";
    $i=0;@r=();
    #### begin count
    $c=127;$l=length($_=$z);while($l>1){if(/(.{$l}).*\1/){push@r,$1;++$c;s/$1/chr($c)/eg}else{$l--}}$z=$_;map{++$i;$x=chr(127+$i);$z=~s:$x:<TAG$i>$_</TAG$i>:g}@r
    #### end count 157 chars
    ## output doesn't count
    ;print "output : $z\n","="x80,"\n"
    }

__END__
perl tags2.pl
input : LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe15
00s,whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimenbook

output : <TAG1>LoremIpsum</TAG1>i<TAG11>ss</TAG11><TAG12>im</TAG12>ply<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2><TAG6>oft</TAG6><TAG13>he</TAG13><TAG4>p
rint</TAG4><TAG7>ing</TAG7><TAG8>and</TAG8><TAG5>types</TAG5>e<TAG14>tt</TAG14><TAG7>ing</TAG7><TAG3>industry</TAG3>.<TAG1>LoremIpsu
m</TAG1>hasbe<TAG15>en</TAG15><TAG9>the</TAG9><TAG3>industry</TAG3>'<TAG11>ss</TAG11>t<TAG8>and</TAG8>ard<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2>ev<TA
G16>er</TAG16>since<TAG9>the</TAG9>1500s,w<TAG13>he</TAG13>nanunknown<TAG4>print</TAG4><TAG16>er</TAG16>t<TAG10>ook</TAG10>agal<TAG1
7>le</TAG17>y<TAG6>oft</TAG6>y<TAG18>pe</TAG18><TAG8>and</TAG8>scramb<TAG17>le</TAG17>di<TAG14>tt</TAG14>omakea<TAG5>types</TAG5><TA
G18>pe</TAG18>c<TAG12>im</TAG12><TAG15>en</TAG15>b<TAG10>ook</TAG10>
================================================================================
input : oktooktobookokm
output : <TAG1>okto</TAG1><TAG1>okto</TAG1>bo<TAG2>ok</TAG2><TAG2>ok</TAG2>m
================================================================================
input : dino1</dino2</
output : <TAG1>dino</TAG1>1<TAG2></</TAG2><TAG1>dino</TAG1>2<TAG2></</TAG2>
================================================================================
input : dino1TAG2dino3TAG
output : <TAG1>dino</TAG1>1<TAG2>TAG</TAG2>2<TAG1>dino</TAG1>3<TAG2>TAG</TAG2>
================================================================================
```

Comment: This does not cover strings of length 2, only 3 and above

Comment: Tagged "ok" instead of "ook" in Loremipsum (see last word)

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <strike>236</strike> 206 chars

```
s="LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimenbook."
### ------------------------------------------------------------
import re
c=o=127
l={}
i=len(s)/2
while i>1:
    r=re.search('(.{%d}).*\\1'%i,s)
    if r:f=r.group(1);c+=1;l[c-o]=f;s=s.replace(f,chr(c))
    else:i-=1
for i in l:s=re.sub(chr(i+o),'<TAG%d>%s</TAG%d>'%(i,l[i],i),s)
### ------------------------------------------------------------
print s
```

And the result of running this on the example input, it picks the following words  *('LoremIpsum', 'dummytext', 'industry', 'print', 'types', 'oft', 'ing', 'and', 'the', 'ook', 'ss', 'im', 'he', 'tt', 'en', 'er', 'le', 'pe')* and the result is:

```
<TAG1>LoremIpsum</TAG1>i<TAG11>ss</TAG11><TAG12>im</TAG12>ply<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2><TAG6>oft</TAG6><TAG13>he</TAG13><TAG4>print</TAG4><TAG7>ing</TAG7><TAG8>and</TAG8><TAG5>types</TAG5>e<TAG14>tt</TAG14><TAG7>ing</TAG7><TAG3>industry</TAG3>.<TAG1>LoremIpsum</TAG1>hasbe<TAG15>en</TAG15><TAG9>the</TAG9><TAG3>industry</TAG3>'<TAG11>ss</TAG11>t<TAG8>and</TAG8>ard<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2>ev<TAG16>er</TAG16>since<TAG9>the</TAG9>1500s,w<TAG13>he</TAG13>nanunknown<TAG4>print</TAG4><TAG16>er</TAG16>t<TAG10>ook</TAG10>agal<TAG17>le</TAG17>y<TAG6>oft</TAG6>y<TAG18>pe</TAG18><TAG8>and</TAG8>scramb<TAG17>le</TAG17>di<TAG14>tt</TAG14>omakea<TAG5>types</TAG5><TAG18>pe</TAG18>c<TAG12>im</TAG12><TAG15>en</TAG15>b<TAG10>ook</TAG10>.
```

Which is more readable on this wiki highlighted like this:

<kbd>LoremIpsum</kbd>i<kbd>ss</kbd><kbd>im</kbd>ply<kbd>dummytext</kbd><kbd>oft</kbd><kbd>he</kbd><kbd>print</kbd><kbd>ing</kbd><kbd>and</kbd><kbd>types</kbd>e<kbd>tt</kbd><kbd>ing</kbd><kbd>industry</kbd>.<kbd>LoremIpsum</kbd>hasbe<kbd>en</kbd><kbd>the</kbd><kbd>industry</kbd>'<kbd>ss</kbd>t<kbd>and</kbd>ard<kbd>dummytext</kbd>ev<kbd>er</kbd>since<kbd>the</kbd>1500s,w<kbd>he</kbd>nanunknown<kbd>print</kbd><kbd>er</kbd>t<kbd>ook</kbd>agal<kbd>le</kbd>y<kbd>oft</kbd>y<kbd>pe</kbd><kbd>and</kbd>scramb<kbd>le</kbd>di<kbd>tt</kbd>omakea<kbd>types</kbd><kbd>pe</kbd>c<kbd>im</kbd><kbd>en</kbd>b<kbd>ook</kbd>.

PS. Somebody complained so I added input and output statements. To the confused I apologize - it seemed obvious to me. Apparently not, so I added prefix/trailer statements, which are not required by the problem spec and should not be counted to the code length.

Comment: What does the range(32) mean here? Does it mean it can handle only upto a length of 32 characters (sorry can't read python... yet!)

Comment: -1: Doesn't follow specs, s is undefined, and no output even when s is defined.

Comment: @trinithis: the spec does not request I/O to be done, hence my code takes string `s` as input and it's output is returned in `s` too. You may call this cutting corners if you want but you cannot say it does NOT follow spec! See the Perl solution, it also does not count input/output

Comment: What I meant about specs is that you are using <T> over <TAG>

Comment: @trinithis: I understood "tagging should be **of the form** <TAG#>" to mean that it should be "something of the kind of", "a-la" - and I chose shorter tags. Anyway changed the tags now to appease you.

Comment: You didn't tag "im" in sIMply and specIMen

Comment: @M42: you were right, thanks for pointing out - there was a bug. i fixed it, as well as the results.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell: 343/344 <s>403</s> <s>420</s> <s>445</s> <s>485</s> characters

Character count is 343 while using an exponential algorithm, whereas it is 344 when using a quadratic algorithm.

The code posted is the quadratic one. For the exponential algorithm, change the one occurrence of `inits=<<tails` to `subsequences` in the code.

```
import Data.List
l=length
e=map$either id id
(&)=stripPrefix
y@(_:w)!x=l x>1&&maybe(w!x)(isInfixOf x)(x&y)
_!_=0<0
t@(x,i)?s@(y:z)=maybe(y:t?z)(((map Right$'<':v++e x++"</"++v)++).(t?))$x&s where v="TAG"++i++">"
_?_=[]
r s=e$foldr(?)s$zip(sortBy(\a b->compare(l a)$l b)$filter(s!)$inits=<<tails s)$map show[1..]
main=getLine>>=putStr.r.map Left
```

Input 1:

```
LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimenbook.
```

Output 1:

```
<TAG338>LoremIpsum</TAG338>i<TAG72>ss</TAG72><TAG122>im</TAG122>ply<TAG336>dummytext</TAG336><TAG188>oft</TAG188><TAG91>he</TAG91><TAG275>print</TAG275><TAG153>ing</TAG153><TAG191>and</TAG191><TAG276>types</TAG276><TAG88>et</TAG88><TAG214>ting</TAG214><TAG328>industry</TAG328>.<TAG338>LoremIpsum</TAG338>hasbe<TAG123>en</TAG123><TAG183>the</TAG183><TAG328>industry</TAG328>'s<TAG73>st</TAG73><TAG191>and</TAG191>ard<TAG336>dummytext</TAG336>ev<TAG99>er</TAG99>s<TAG96>in</TAG96>ce<TAG183>the</TAG183>1500s,wh<TAG123>en</TAG123><TAG111>an</TAG111>unknown<TAG275>print</TAG275><TAG99>er</TAG99>t<TAG195>ook</TAG195>a<TAG103>ga</TAG103>l<TAG113>le</TAG113>y<TAG105>of</TAG105><TAG241>type</TAG241><TAG191>and</TAG191>scramb<TAG113>le</TAG113>dit<TAG115>to</TAG115>mak<TAG116>ea</TAG116><TAG276>types</TAG276><TAG121>pe</TAG121>c<TAG122>im</TAG122><TAG123>en</TAG123>b<TAG195>ook</TAG195>.
```

Input 2:

```
hello!TAG!</hello.TAG.</
```

Output 2:

```
<TAG28>hello</TAG28>!<TAG22>TAG</TAG22>!<TAG14></</TAG14><TAG28>hello</TAG28>.<TAG22>TAG</TAG22>.<TAG14></</TAG14>
```

Comment: you should be able to tighten your algorithm so that it can run against the problem example in reasonable time - see there is at least one other solution that does not rely on regex magic

Comment: Come to think of it, using `inits=<<tails x` is only one more character than `subsequences x`, yet runs in polynomial time. Worth it or not? (Think code-golf!)

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think you can use [back references](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) to do this. See this post : [Regular Expression to detect repetition within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943872/regular-expression-to-detect-repetition-within-a-string)
I've done many attempts and for the moment I have this expression: #([a-zA-Z ]+).*\1#, but I think it finds the first repeated string, not the largest...</del>
This was before I knew you didn't care about words...
What you should do is:

- find the largest sequence of characters repeated in the text
- remove it from the text where it appears
- iterate until you find nothing repeated
- use tomit's method to colorize the strings you have memorized

the step is described on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem
And here is a php implementation : http://www.davidtavarez.com/archives/longer-common-substring-problem-php-implementation/ (you'll have to fix it, it contains html entities, and the comment says it returns an integer but we don't know what it represents...), if it still does not work, you can try to implement wikipedia's pseudo-code.

Comment: Do you think its worthwhile to post this as a code golf challenge??

Comment: tomit had posted an intersting answer regarding the search and replace function to colorize the string, but seems to have withdrawed it, probably because he thought this was off-board. Never mind, it is no very difficult to do with str_replace. For the code golf, you might try, or you may even offer a bounty for this question...

Comment: ^ str_replace yields incorrect output for some inputs (at least if done naively).

Answer (score 0):

### Python, <del>236</del> *281 chars*, no REGEX :)

Makes a set `M` of all 2+ character strings then iterates through them to assign them in greedy-length order

```
s="LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimenbook."
#s="abcd1TAGabcd2TAG"

### ----
L,C,R=len,chr,range
M,l,T,t=set(),L(s),[],0
[[M.add(s[A:B])for B in R(A+2,l)]for A in R(l)]
while 1:
 m,t=sorted([(L(m),m)if s.count(m)>1 else(0,"")for m in M])[-1][1],t+1
 if m=="":break
 T+=[(t,m)]
 s=s.replace(m,C(t))
for(t,m)in T:
 s=s.replace(C(t),"<TAG%d>%s</TAG%d>"%(t,m,t))
### ----

print s
```

Outputs, as expected:

> ```
> <TAG1>LoremIpsum</TAG1>i<TAG11>ss</TAG11><TAG15>im</TAG15>ply<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2><TAG13>of</TAG13><TAG6>the</TAG6><TAG5>print</TAG5><TAG8>ing</TAG8><TAG9>and</TAG9><TAG4>types</TAG4>e<TAG10>tt</TAG10><TAG8>ing</TAG8><TAG3>industry</TAG3>.<TAG1>LoremIpsum</TAG1>hasbe<TAG17>en</TAG17><TAG6>the</TAG6><TAG3>industry</TAG3>'<TAG11>ss</TAG11>t<TAG9>and</TAG9>ard<TAG2>dummytext</TAG2>ev<TAG16>er</TAG16>since<TAG6>the</TAG6>1500s,wh<TAG17>en</TAG17>anunknown<TAG5>print</TAG5><TAG16>er</TAG16>t<TAG7>ook</TAG7>agal<TAG14>le</TAG14>y<TAG13>of</TAG13>ty<TAG12>pe</TAG12><TAG9>and</TAG9>scramb<TAG14>le</TAG14>di<TAG10>tt</TAG10>omakea<TAG4>types</TAG4><TAG12>pe</TAG12>c<TAG15>im</TAG15><TAG17>en</TAG17>b<TAG7>ook</TAG7>.
> ```

Comment: Code breaks with `abcd1TAGabcd2TAG`

Comment: errr, problem: see how in `<TAG4>ty<TAG12>pe</TAG12>s</TAG4>` tags overlap?

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica - 262 Chars

Not pure functional / Not short / Not nice / Lots of side effects /

```
b = "LoremIpsumissimplydummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.\
     LoremIpsumhasbeentheindustry'sstandarddummytexteversincethe1500s,\
     whenanunknownprintertookagalleyoftypeandscrambledittomakeatypespecimen\
     book."

i = 0
a = c = "@"
v = StringFreeQ@## &
w = StringReplace@## &
t = x__ ~~ y__ ~~ __ ~~ x__ ~~ y__ /; v[x <> y, c]
NestWhile[
  w[#, (a = SortBy[StringCases[#, t -> x <> y,Overlaps -> True], -StringLength@# &][[1]]) -> c] &,
  b,
  (z = k@++i; b = w[b, a -> "<TAG" <> z <> ">" <> a <> "</TAG" <> z <> ">"] /. k -> IntegerString; True) && ! v[#, t] &]
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) who helped me arrive at this approach by answering a few related questions I had on shell scripting - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210132/how-to-use-unix-scripts-to-show-all-n-characters-long-group-of-strings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218241/shell-script-to-find-search-and-replace-array-of-strings-in-a-file).

Known issues with the below:

1. It works only for ascii files and not binary ones
2. It works only if there are no newlines in the file
3. It takes exponentially longer as the file gets longer
4. It breaks easily on files more than a few kb long (runs out of tmp disk space)

As you can see, its a huge brute-force method - not a smart algorithm at all. I've recorded the time taken for a few sample files.

```
bytes  time(s)
204 1.281
407 24.916
610 269.302
```

The point of even doing this as I did below was more about a "thought-challenge" for me - to do this in a shell environment and in a manner as "complete" as possible. Nothing more. Of course, as the results show, its grossly inefficient, so its completely unsuited for a real world application.

```
filesize=`stat -c %s $1`
while [ $filesize -gt 1 ]
do
        filesize=`expr $filesize - 1`
        array=( "${array[@]}" $(cat $1 | sed -n ":a;/^.\{$filesize\}$/{p;b};s/.\{$filesize\}/&\n/;P;s/.//;s/\n//;ba" | sort | uniq -c | grep -v '      1' | cut -c9-) )
done

sample=$(<$1)
tag=0;
for entry in ${array[@]};
        do
        test="<[^>/]*>[^>]*$entry[^<]*</";
        if [[ ! $sample =~ $test ]];
                then ((tag++));
                sample=${sample//${entry}/<T$tag>$entry</T$tag>};
        fi;
        done;
echo $sample
```

Usage would be as:

```
sh tagwords4 sample2.txt
```