# How to use unix scripts to show all 'n' characters long group of strings?

Tags: unix, shell, grep, cut

This IS kind of linked to another question - [Code golf: "Color highlighting" of repeated text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171552/code-golf-color-highlighting-of-repeated-text)

I'm tying to figure out a way of breaking a file into all 'n' characters long groups.

Eg: If a file comprises of ONLY the following text:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

And we want it broken into sets of 3, the output should be:

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
DEF
EFG
FGH
GHI
HIJ
```

No characters in the file are to be treated any differently from another. ie, a "space" is just another character which should follow the rule above...

Comment: Which shell are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Are newlines characters?  Can there be multi-byte characters?

Comment: Hi yahoo.co.jp* - that would make things interesting! But no, for the moment, I dont need that capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed:

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJ" | sed -n ':a;/^...$/{p;b};s/.../&\n/;P;s/.//;s/\n//;ba'
```

A more generalized `sed` version:

```
num=5; echo "ABCDEFGHIJ" | sed -n ":a;/^.\{$num\}\$/{p;b};s/.\{$num\}/&\n/;P;s/.//;s/\n//;ba"
```

Bash and ksh:

```
string="ABCDEFGHIJ"
for ((i=0;i<=${#string}-3;i++)); do echo ${string:i:3}; done
```

zsh:

```
string="ABCDEFGHIJ"
for ((i=1;i<=${#string}-2;i++)); do echo $string[i,i+2]; done
```

sh (specifically Dash):

```
string='ABCDEFGHIJ'
count=$(seq $((${#string}-2)))
for i in $count; do b="$b?"; done
for i in $count; do b="${b%?}"; echo "${string%$b}"; string="${string#?}"; done
```

AWK:

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJ" | awk -v num=4 '{for (i=1; i<length($0)-num;i++) print substr($0,i,num)}'
```

**Edit:** Added a more generalized `sed` version and an AWK version.

Comment: AWESOME! The sed solution works perfectly and with spaces in there too! I figured the 3 dots are for the "number of characters" and tested it out for other "lengths" as well!! Excellent!!

Comment: Just wondering - isnt there a more straightforward solution with 'dd' and a loop?

Comment: @RubiCon10: `dd`? Huh? I suppose you could duct-tape something together, but I'd use one of the shell loops in my answer before I'd try to do that. I wouldn't use a road grader to till my flower beds, either. See my edit for a more generalized `sed` version and an AWK version.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be shell based or are you open to other scripting languages?  Here's a version in Python:

```
width = 3
data = open("file").read()
for x in xrange(len(data) - width + 1):
    print data[x : x+width]
```