# Replace array of string ( passed as argument to script ) replace those values in a HQL file using Bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hive, hql

I have a script which accepts 3 arguments $1 $2 $3

but $3 is an array like ("2018" "01")

so I am executing my script as :

```
sh script.sh Employee IT "2018 01"
```

and there an HQL file ( emp.hql) in which I want to replace my partition columns with the array passed like below :

```
***"select deptid , employee_name from {TBL_NM} where year={par_col[i]} and month={par_col[i]}"***
```

so below is the code I have tried :

```
**Table=$1
dept=$2
Par_cols=($3)
 for i in "${par_cols[@]}" ;do
sed -i "/${par_col[i]}/${par_col[i]}/g" /home/hk/emp.hql**
done
```

Error :

```
*sed: -e experssion #1 , char 0: no previous regular expression*


*sed: -e experssion #2 , char 0: no previous regular expression*
```

But I think logic to replace partition columns is wrong , could you please help me in this?

**Desired Output in HQL file :**

```
select deptid ,employee_name from employee where year=2018 and month=01
```

Little bit related to below like :

[Shell script to find, search and replace array of strings in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218241/shell-script-to-find-search-and-replace-array-of-strings-in-a-file)

Comment: `sh does not have arrays`

Comment: is there any way I can solve above issue?