# How to find sequenced pattern of characters in a string with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

Let's say I have random block of text:

```
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
```

SPECIFICATIONS:

```
patternABC >= 2 characters = groupABC IF groupABC occurs more than once
groupABC + (groupABC)n = sequence WHERE n >= 1 AND sequence > 6 characters
```

** A sequence needs to be > 6 characters in order to be evaluated

BREAKDOWN:

How do I find any repeating patterns that occur in sequence?

```
QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA
```

I also want to count how many times each group repeats:

```
QEBA QEBA QEBA QEBA QEBA QEBA = 6
```

Also the sequence must be > 6 characters in order to be evaluated:

```
NO GOOD: AA AA AA
GOOD: AA AA AA AA
```

It would be ideal if the output could be stored in an associative array, with duplicate entries removed:

```
QEBA => 6, AA => 4, QEBA => 3, AA => 8, (QEBA => 6)<- REMOVE
```

Does anyone have the time & the inclination to tackle this problem?
You rock if you do!

Comment: probable duplicate of [Regular Expression to detect repetition within a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/943872), second answer.

Comment: this regex: `/((\w+?)(\2))+/g` will match all repeating sequences of letters. Then I guess you need to manipulate them a bit.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies!

@BillyMoon That regex looks like it could definitely help. Thanks.

Comment: "in groups of 2 or more"? Repeated 2 or more times? Or at least 2 characters to be repeated? What about `AAAAAABAAAAAAB`? Are there `AA`s, `AAAAAAB`s, or both repeating? What about `ABABABCBCBC`, should `AB`, `BC` or both be counted?

Comment: patternABC >= 2 characters = groupABC
groupABC + (groupABC)n = sequence WHERE n >= 1 AND sequence > 6 characters

** A sequence needs to be > 6 characters in order to be evaluated

I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Just modified the explanation of the question to clarify things a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = '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';

preg_match_all( '/(\S{2,}?)\1+/', $str, $matches );

// Remove duplicates
$matches[0] = array_unique( $matches[0] ); 

foreach ( $matches[0] as $key => $value ) {
    if ( strlen( $value ) > 6 ) {
        $repeated = $matches[1][$key];
        $results[] = array( $repeated => count( explode( $repeated, $value ) ) - 1 );
    }    
}

print_r($results); 

/*
[AA] => 7
[QEBA] => 93
[CAgI] => 18
[EBAQ] => 18
*/
```

The above assumes a sequence is composed of non-space characters.

Comment: I need to know each sequence & how many groups contained within, as it occurs. So if QEBA occurs 6 times in one place & 18 times in another place, that's how I want to store it. QEBA => 6, QEBA => 18

Comment: @o0110o. The output is stored in an array of associative arrays, each containing a sequence as the key, and the repeat count as its value. This means the same sequence can be now stored multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: So as it turns out, what I was trying to achieve was the similar to GZIP, so that's what I ended up using in the end.
I tried these answers & I found that @MikeM gave a more robust answer that I was able to implement easily, although I really liked the regex examples provided by @ ka.
Thanks again everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Get the sequences with `preg_match_all('/(?:(.{6,})\1)/',$inputText,$sequences)`
*(note: sequences will be saved in `$sequences`)*
Explained RegEx demo: http://regex101.com/r/rW4nE2

Use [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get rid of duplicates.

Loop through each sequence and:
Get the groups with `preg_match_all('/(.+?)(\1)(\1)?/',$sequence,$groups)`
Explained RegEx demo: http://regex101.com/r/pC3pB7

Use [count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) if you need to.

Comment: you might also like [base64_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Comment: Thank-you so much!
I will try this out & mark your answer as correct if it works.

Also, is there anyway to get preg_match_all('/(.+?)(\1)(\1)?/',$sequence,$groups) to output the smallest possible pattern?
Should I just run it again using groups[0] for input?

Comment: Excellent, this example threw me off a little: http://regex101.com/r/pC3pB7.

Again, thank-you for your help. Thanks to everyone else that is trying to help as well!

Comment: You're welcome. The only thing that's repeating there is `CAgI`. See this one also: http://regex101.com/r/jH8dV3