# Find the number of occurring strings within a string but starting with specific character

Tags: php, regex

My problem is similar to this question:

[How to find sequenced pattern of characters in a string with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325735/how-to-find-sequenced-pattern-of-characters-in-a-string-with-php)

But I need to extend the regex in order to take under consideration strings that begin with `_` (underscore).

So how is this regex `'/(\S{2,}?)\1+/'` extended in order to match my need?

EX

The string `'parent_parent_parent.parent'` should return `[_parent] => 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Biffen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions is not even a question and the answer is a general guide to regular expressions. Sure not what I was looking for.

Comment: Are you sure? A perfect fit, IMO.

Comment: @Biffen Ok I will start reading, then. Even though I was hoping for a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your need is "find all repeating substrings that start with an underscore", just add the underscore to the regular expression: `/(_[\S]{2,}?)\1+/`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

There is a function in PHP called `substr_count` that did the same trick.

Similar function: `mb_substr_count`.

```
$str = "parent_parent_parent.parent";

echo substr_count($str, "_parent"); // 2
```

Comment: The string is not known that's why I need a regex